# How do I create a dataframe in python, based on the group-by function and different aggregations?

Tags: dataframe, group-by, count, median

[image]

I have a dataframe, df, in Python which looks like the image below:

I would like to create a second dataframe, based on the first, where for each salesperson I summarize:

1. The number of distinct customers they sold to
2. Their median "Qauntities sold"
3. Their total sum of Sales

I know I have to group by the column "Salesperson Name", but I would like help on how to approach this in Python. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of how you could achieve that

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Salesperson':[1,2,2,4,1,5],
                    'Customer':[1,2,3,1,1,2],
                    'Sold':[5,6,7,1,2,2],
                    'Sales':[50,25,75,100,10,30]})

print(df)

df_summary = df.\
    groupby("Salesperson").\
    agg(
        distinct = ("Customer",lambda x: x.nunique()),
        sold_median = ("Sold","median"),
        sales_total = ("Sales","sum")
        )
print(df_summary)
```